# Facebook php sdk login issue using getUser()

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a php script using Facebooks sdk which logins using the following code:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' =>      ($user['baseurl'].'logout.php') ));
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'offline_access, manage_pages, publish_stream'));
}

if ($user) {
  echo '<div class="login"><a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout</a></div>';
}
else {
  echo '<div class="login">
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>';
}
```

The script refreshes and posts to my facebook wall once an hour for a total of nine hours.  The problem is that randomly getUser() will fail and I will be forced to manually login again.  I'm not sure what's causing the getUser() failure or how to fix it?

Comment: Based only on what you just said, it sounds like its login session is simply timing out while it's waiting during that 1 hr period. A simple solution is for it to access it at intervals during that hour, simply to keep its session active  even though it's not posting anything further.

Comment: Strange thing is it only happens sometimes, not everytime.

Comment: Does it ever happen back to back, or every few hours it does it? Assuming it's timing out its session, it could simply be that it works a couple times before it times out, thus it seems as if it's random but really just a matter of what the timeout duration is. I'll poke around on my end, and see what I can further turn up for you.

Comment: The permissions offline_access and publish_stream doesn't exists. And you are using an old version of the SDK

Comment: As WizKid just mentioned, it seems those have been deprecated with the newer versions. From what I was reading, it seems that they use a token system now, and you'll need to utilize that to further extend the tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

That'll get you pointed in the right direction hopefully. Hope it helps. I'll keep poking around for you. Let me know if it works out.

Comment: No problem bro. I'm still looking around for you and finding some other useful information. What version of the SDK are you using? There is an article from last year, and seems to be more up to date than some of the other stuff I was reading. http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/    It seems to directly answer, and show you, how to go about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for spamming. Here is some more information on the helper classes you can use to accomplish your goal also.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Time for me to leave work, so I must depart. Hope it works out for ya bro!

Comment: Thanks for the links!  Looked into updating my sdk to the newest version but my website runs php 5.3 right now... scared that upgrading to 5.4 (which I need for sdk 4.0) will cause some unforseen problem.  What I ended up doing is implementing the very first idea of refreshing the page various times throughout the hours... looks like that did the trick!